# Change the value in a multidimensionnal array with foreach in php

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array that come from a MySQL table with 8 column. 2 of them are dates, and I want to update one of those by adding 1 week. Here is what I did :

```
foreach ($datas as &$data_rows) {
    if($data_rows[3] == "Each week"){
        $date = strtotime($data_rows[6]);
        $data_rows[1] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 week", $date));
    }
}
```

There is a lot of job with many different frequencies, so what I'm trying to do is first, add to the last time the job have been done the frequency (+ 1 week, +1 month, etc.) and doing that with that example here (and some else if for the other frequency), so I need to update the dates in 1 column

Then I want to sort those date so the first lane will be the first job to do. but for that, I need to update a column of my array.

It's just not working, if I do stuff in the foreach, it's ok, but as soon the foreach is over, I can't uses it anymore, the data are not saved...

Comment: you need to show initial sample array data and what you expected as outcome (that array also). As well as what code you are using at last for inserting record.?Add all this to your question to make it more clear to others, so that they can answer

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easiest to use a for loop and just reference you indexes with the counter.

Providing your dates that you are trying to convert are a legitimate date string then this should work for you.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    if($data[$i][3] == 'Each week') {
        $data[$i][1] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data[$i][6] . ' +1 week'));
    }
}
```